# Why react-router-config not found?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to do Server side rendering for my React Js App.I'm following [this course](https://www.udemy.com/server-side-rendering-with-react-and-redux/) from Udemy

When i tried to import `renderRoutes` from `react-router-config` into my client.js file,it showing bellow error on terminal.but i have already installed `react-router-config` to my App.

[image]

**Client.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Routes from './Routes';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import promise from 'redux-promise';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { hotjar } from 'react-hotjar';
import reducers from './reducers';
import { HOTJAR_ID, HOTJAR_VERSION } from './common/common';
import { renderRoutes } from 'react-router-config';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promise)(createStore);
hotjar.initialize(HOTJAR_ID, HOTJAR_VERSION);

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(reducers, composeEnhancers(
  applyMiddleware(promise, thunk)
));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>{renderRoutes(Routes)}</div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

**Package.json**

[image]

Comment: Is that your entire `Client.js`? I'm not seeing imports for `Provider` or `BrowserRouter`. And `store` is undefined.

Comment: @ChrisG i have updated my client.js file

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem such way - insert this dependencies:

```
"react-router": "4.3.1",
"react-router-config": "1.0.0-beta.4",
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
```

and run "npm install"